# Spark flatmap: how much memory can a map task get?

Tags: apache-spark

Hi I am using have an rdd containing tuple of arrays,  i.e. of type
RDD[(Array[Int], Array[Int])]

```
rdd = sc.parallelize(Array( (Array(1, 2, 3), Array(3,4, 5))
                            (Array(5, 6, 7), Array(4,5, 6))
                            ....
                          ))
```

and I am trying to do the following :

```
rdd.flatMap{ case (arr1, arr2) => 
   (for(i <- arr1; j <- arr2) yield (i, j) )
 }
```

And I noticed that as I increase the sizes of the arrays from 500 to 5000, the runtime increase from several minutes to about 10 minutes,

however, if I increase the sizes of the arrays from 5K to 6K, the runtime of this operations increase to several hours.

So I am wondering why I am getting such a big increase in runtime from 5K to 6K, while from 1k to 5k runtime increase smoothly?

I am suspecting that may be the memory limit of map task is reached, and disk operations are involved, resulting in the long runtime, but the sizes is not really big, since I allocated 14G memory and 8 cores to Spark in local mode.

Comment: What is the amount of cores available in your machine . You have assigned the memory 14G and 8 cores does your machine has that much of cores and RAM ?

Comment: I would take a look at the Spark UI and see how the jobs get distributed. Maybe a single executor is doing all the work because of data skew. Also you can inspect garbage collection time here, which would explode in runtime in case of insufficient memory.